# .htaccess not replacing url

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I have the .htaccess file in the main folder of my cpanel file directory along with the rest of my files. And for some reason it does not work. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: can you provide some input URLs and the expected vs the actual outcome?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the end?